# How do I configure gnome-screensaver?

Tags: installation, gnome, gui, screensaver

I am on ubuntu 12.10 and installed gnome-screensaver but I can't find any way to configure them or launch gnome-screensaver-preferences. f1.

I installed and got away with xscreensaver, now want to use gnome-screensaver. Ran this in terminal : `sudo apt-get install gnome-screensaver`.

Now how to configure or change them ? Like is there any GUI support for the same? I tried installing gnome screensaver and locker package from here :- https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/quantal/+source/gnome-screensaver

A .deb file, but to no avail. all help be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think xscreensaver is much better. After I switched to xfce DE I uninstalled gnome-screensaver at once or it would prevent xscreensaver from working. Gnome-screensaver now only show you a black screen while xscreensaver can show you many more wonderful animations.